# What does the additional colon mean in a templated class. ClassName<T, SIZE>::ClassName:

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

What does the additional ':' mean in this function definition?

```
template <class T, int SIZE> 
class Buffer
{
 public: 
    Buffer();
 private: 
    int _num_items; 
};

template <class T, int SIZE> 
Buffer<T, SIZE>::Buffer() :
    _num_items(0) //What does this line mean?? 
{
   //Some additional code for constructor goes here. 
}
```

Comment: Search for "constructor initialization list"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can initialize member variables (and you should do that)

```
class Something
{
private:
  int aValue;
  AnotherThing *aPointer;

public:
  Something() 
   : aValue(5), aPointer(0)
  {
     printf(aValue); // prints 5
     if(aPointer == 0) // will be 0 here
       aPointer = new AnotherThing ();
  }
}
```

It's the initialisation list - the members will be initialized with the given value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so would this only apply to a templated class or can it apply to any class?

Comment: Any class can initialize its members that way. In your case its a template class but this initialisation list applies to all classes in C++. Just google `c++ constructor initialization list`

Comment: Thank you. This site is awesome. Some of this stuff i wouldnt even know where to start when it came to finding it.

Comment: You're welcome. stackoverflow truly rocks! If you want to accept an answer you can click the check mark on the left side so users can see that this question has got an answer btw :)

Comment: I was waiting because i guess that you have to wait for 10 minutes to select an answer. That set me on the right track.

Comment: Oh I see :) Well, have a nice programming!